# Differentiation Under the Integral Sign with Variable Substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $\psi(x,\xi)$ take inputs $x = (x_1,...,x_n),\ \xi = (\xi_1,...,\xi_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\psi$ have continuous first partial derivatives. I wish to show that

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\int_{B_r(x)} \psi(x,\xi)\ d\xi = \int_{B_r(x)} \psi_{x_j}(x,\xi) + \psi_{\xi_j}(x,\xi)\ d\xi $$

I've made the variable substitution $\eta = \xi - x$ which has yielded

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\int_{B_r(x)} \psi(\xi-\eta,\xi)\ d\xi $$

This feels like the correct direction but how would I differentiate $\psi$ with this variable substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that $x$ occurs in the region of integration. As long as that is the case, we cannot take the derivative without using the (rather complicated) [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Higher_dimensions) in higher dimensions. Simply renaming the variables and using the chain rule does not really help here.

Instead we need to understand $\eta = \xi - x$ as a change of the integration variable. It has unit Jacobian and it shifts the region of integration from $B_r(x)$ to $B_r(0)$. This yields
$$\int_{B_r(x)} \psi(x,\xi) \, \mathrm{d} \xi = \int_{B_r(0)} \psi(x,\eta + x) \, \mathrm{d} \eta \, .$$
Let $\partial_k \psi$ denote the partial derivative of $\psi$ with respect to the $k$-th variable for $1 \leq k \leq 2n$ . Then by the chain rule we have
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \psi(x,\eta + x) = \partial_j \psi(x,\eta+x) + \partial_{n+j} \psi(x,\eta+x) \, , \, 1 \leq j \leq n \, .$$
We can now differentiate under the integral sign and return to the original variable of integration afterwards to obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}  \int_{B_r(x)} \psi(x,\xi) \, \mathrm{d} \xi &=  \int_{B_r(0)} [\partial_j \psi(x,\eta+x) + \partial_{n+j} \psi(x,\eta+x)] \, \mathrm{d} \eta \\
&= \int_{B_r(x)} [\partial_j \psi(x,\xi) + \partial_{n+j} \psi(x,\xi)] \, \mathrm{d} \xi \\
&= \int_{B_r(x)} \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \psi(x,\xi) + \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi_j} \psi(x,\xi)\right] \, \mathrm{d} \xi
\end{align}
for $1 \leq j \leq n$ as desired.

Comment: Wonderfully explained, thank you.

Comment: @Bailey You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Making the change to $\eta = \xi - x$, then $\partial/\partial x_j$ is taken via the chain rule, since now $\eta$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Thanks. I've written $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_j} + \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x_j}$. Is this the correct form of the chain rule to apply?